# Cannot upgrade from 18.04 up to 19.04 by nvidia driver nightmare

Tags: nvidia, 19.04, do-release-upgrade, 19.10

I have read all nvidia question and try to follow all solution but they not work. 
So I start a new question to restart at beginning.

I have a ubuntu 18.04 and nvidia 435 driver well working (on gtx 750 Ti).

After I try to upgrade to 19.04 it freeze at boot before grub options.
So I cannot go on Ctrl-Alt-F2 to investigate or change grub options.

I have upgrade to 19.04 an then before reboot I have do all workaround seen in all ubuntu questions and then reboot but nothing work.

I went back by using previous clonezilla image to restere to 18.04

I do this 100 times.

If I start Ubuntu 19.04 or Ubuntu 19.10 by ISO image and try it it will work but it install nouvou and this drive make see my video screen.

I have change sudo vim /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
adding to it needs_root_rights = yes but nothing work.

If in 19.10 ISO are nvidia driver well working why if I try the iso it do not use nvidia driver?

On my 18.04 I have a ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa installed

After upgrade to 19.04 before reboot I have try to add it back and remove all nvidia* and then reinstall 435 version but it freeze at reboot.

It is hard to me to do a backup and install a new fresh ubuntu. Too many reinstallation and configuration and sure I forget something.

I have to upgrade. There is a way to upgrade from 18.04 to 19.40 and use nvidia driver?

In my grub setting I have nomodeset added

$ cat /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config

```
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command as root:
#   dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
allowed_users=console
#per nvidia problem on gdm
needs_root_rights = yes
```

$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
# per Nvivia GTX 750ti
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
```

I have try to add and remove Wayland=false from /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Nothing work.

Can someone help?

Best regard and forgive me for duplicate

--
after ubfan1 reply I try and freeze at startup.

[my boot log](https://pastebin.com/yLTFjD8u)

### Update

The ubfan1 solution was right.
I have forget to delete **nomodeset** from my ubuntu grub options.
So after boot on live cd I chrooted and delete **nomodeset** end update grub.

After this the noveau driver work.

After reboot I use apt without extern ppa to install best nvidia driver (435) for my gpu.

All work Thanks very match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with the nouveau driver in use, remove the graphics-driver ppa, purge all the nvidia packages, and undo any modifications you made to the system files.  I just ran a clean upgrade 18.04/19.04/19.10 with nouveau, then installed the nvidia driver.  Some things are different -- I don't see any blacklist of nouveau in any modprobe.d file!  Even before install the 19.10 Nvidia driver, I didn't see "nomodeset" in use anywhere.  You may not even need the graphids-driver ppa anymore.  If you do, you can reinstall it after the upgrade.

---

I don't see anything much in the boot log except the failure to load kernel modules.  That might be the clue to what's causing problems.
The original 18.04 was running nouveau and never had any Nvidia drivers installed. After getting to 19.10, I installed the Nvidia 390 driver (the one recommended for my Quadro 1000M hardware). The two upgrades (18.04/19.04/19.10) went without issue.

Comment: I have do but stop at startup with [ ok ] started gdm3 and no video screen. need help please. I can mount root partition under live ubuntu end post log if help.

Comment: I have add my boot log in my question

Comment: @ubfan1 I have a similar issue on 19.10.  Are you running nvidia 435 on 19.10 or still nouveau

Comment: Kevin I have resolved using ubfan1 solution and scratch nomodeset from grub options. I updated my question above.  All work to me now and I use 19.10 and 435. regards